# Is this the correct way of refreshing the drawing in a different view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

- Import the CustomView.h in the data controller header file
- Create an IBoutlet to my CustomView from there
- Connect that outlet instoryboard from the DataController to the CustomView
- Use that to call the view's setNeedsDisplay method.

Every time I add an item to the core data context I would like it to notify the CustomView (which lives in another tab) to redraw itself.

I am using ios5 and storyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the DataController should be notifying the view when it needs to refresh because the data has changed, so your implementation is sound.